# Gauss law for moving charges

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, maxwell-equations

since gauss law for electricity is derived from the divergence theorem and couloumbs law. why can it be assumed it is valid for moving charges as coulombs law is only valid for static charges since it has no curl when non moving. so when deriving the wave equation you assume the curl of E is non zero as per faradays law but when you substitute gauss law into it for the full derivation there is still a doubt about why gauss law which is derived from electoSTATICS can be used to convey information about time varying electric signals

Comment: You may improve readability by structuring your text into sentences that start with a capital and ending with a period. In case of a question a question mark is commonly used. Only use capitals for abbreviations otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In electrostatics, Coloumb's law (plus the law of superposition), and Gauss's law, turn out to be equivalent. You can derive either one from the other. Therefore it is in effect a matter of personal preference which one you take as fundamental and which one you take as derived, in electrostatics.

In electrodynamics, the two are no longer equivalent. It turns out that Gauss's law remains true, *always*, even though Coloumb's law breaks down and must be replaced by the Lienard-Wiechert potentials. When I saw "true," I mean that if you take Gauss's law (and the other Maxwell equations) as a starting point, the consequences you derive agree with all experiments involving electromagnetism. As a result, the modern point of view is to take Gauss's law as the more fundamental principle, which is always true in any circumstance (as far as anyone knows), and Columb's law is merely a way of expressing Gauss's law when charges are not moving.

There are other, more sophisticated ways to argue that Gauss's law should hold when there are moving charges (namely, by considering relativity), but at the end of the day the ultimate test is comparison with experiment, and Maxwell's equations (including Gauss's law) pass every experimental test with flying colors.

Comment: anyone still on this thread. after more reading about helmholtz decomposition, if the E field can be composed of a divergenceless component(-dA/dt) and a curlless component(-grad phi) then even when a charge is moving and the e field is affected by the -da/dt terms because by definution of the helm holt decomposition it must he divergenceless so the equation  div e= div(-grad phi )(plus divergence less term) satiafies gauss law as any change to E caused by this added term for magnetism dissappears after you apply the divergence